# TypeError: argument 1 must be pygame.Surface, not builtin_function_or_method (python 3.2.3)

Tags: python, pygame, paint

Okay, so I'm using pygame to create a program, however, when I try to create my rectangle tool, it seems to always display TypeError: argument 1 must be pygame.Surface, not builtin_function_or_method. I'm not sure why, because I asked a peer about it, and it worked perfectly fine, with the same code.

```
from pygame import *
from random import *

screen = display.set_mode((1152,864))

start = 0,0
color = (0,0,0)
canvasRect = Rect(150,160,850,700)
recttoolRect = Rect(20,350,40,40)
draw.rect(screen,(255,255,255),canvasRect)

running = True
while running:
    finish = False
    for e in event.get():
        if e.type == QUIT:
            running = False

        if e.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if e.button == 1:
                start=e.pos
                copy = screen.copy

    mb = mouse.get_pressed()
    mx,my = mouse.get_pos()

    draw.rect(screen,(255,255,255),recttoolRect)

    if mb[0] == 1 and recttoolRect.collidepoint(mx,my):
        tool = rect
    if mb[0] == 1 and canvasRect.collidepoint(mx,my) and tool == rect:
        screen.set_clip(canvasRect)
        screen.blit(copy,(0,0))
        draw.rect(screen,(colour),(start[0],start[1],mx-start[0],my-start[1]))


    display.flip() 
quit()
```

Comment: Can you give us the full traceback?

Comment: Stab in the dark, do you want `screen.copy()` instead of `screen.copy` ?

Comment: Thanks! It turns out that's EXACTLY what happened LOL. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Without the full traceback it is hard to tell, but I'm guessing you've forgotton some parentheses behind a function call somewhere. E.g. if `rect` is a function, you probably have to write `rect()`, not `rect`.

Comment: I'm not really sure how to do a full traceback, but yes! You were right! Thank you. I forgot to write screen.copy() instead of screen.copy, darn it. Thanks for your help!